# Swift 3 interact with tableView during a wilDisplay cell animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I want to make it so you can interact with a tableView before an animation ends, when I try to implement the willDisplay cell function, I get a successful animation, but you can not interact with the cells before the animation is finished.

here is my willDisplay cell code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        cell.alpha = 0.5

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {

            cell.alpha = 1.0

        }

    }
```

When I tried to complete the animation with the didEndDisplaying cell function here, it didn't end up animating at all:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        cell.alpha = 0.5

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {

            cell.alpha = 1.0

        }

    }
```

I have even tried to use a combination of both finctions and still no success:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        cell.alpha = 0.5

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {

            cell.alpha = 1.0

        }

    }
```

My main goal is for the user to be able to continue scrolling down/up the table without having to wait for the animation to finish, but if you can also find a way to interact with buttons as well before the animation completes that would be a bonus.